# How do I shuffle in Python for a column (years) with keeping the corrosponding column values?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file with five columns. First column has year(2011 to 2040), 2nd has Tmax, 3rd has Tmin, 4th has Precip, and fifth has Solar for 30 years. I would like to write a python code which shuffles the first column (year) 10 times with remaining columns having the corresponding original values in them, that is: I want to shuffle year columns only for 10 times so that year 1 will have the corresponding values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the text as a list of rows, each row being a list or tuple of columns. The `csv` module may be useful for this.

Then just shuffle the rows. The `random` module has a function called `shuffle`.

EDIT:

Assuming the input format is CSV (comma separated value):

```
import csv
import random

input_path = r"path\to\input"
output_path = r"path\to\output"

with open(input_path, "rb") as file:
    rows = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))

random.shuffle(rows)

with open(output_path, "wb") as file:
    csv.writer(file, delimiter=",").writerows(rows)
```

Comment: would you please provide me a sample code for this one. i am a beginner in programming. thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help and time. can I get your e-mail so that I can send you the sample file?

Comment: I got the error message like this: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\\\Programming\\\\Practice'################ If I can send you the file I am working on you may be able to find out the problem.

Comment: Your message tells you that you cannot open the file for reading. Check its properties.

Comment: @user1628913: You can send me the file provided that it isn't enormous. :-) You can find my e-mail address in my profile page.

Comment: the file size is about 360 kb, i couldn't find your e-mail id in your profile (MRAB), my email id is crabin5@yahoo.com

Comment: Ah, OK. Try e-mailing me at stackoverflow@mrabarnett.plus.com

Comment: Thank You Tons and Tons !!!MRAB!!! The code worked perfect and with your comments made me learn and understand easier!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with NumPy ? Once you have your data in a numpy `ndarray`, it's a breeze to shuffle the rows while keeping the column orders, without the hurdle of creating many temporaries.

You could use a function like `np.genfromtxt` to read your data file and create a `ndarray` with different named fields. You could then use the `np.random.shuffle` function to reorganize the rows.

Comment: (BTW, if you're interested into computing PET or such, there are some stat libraries in NumPy focused on climate analysis...)